# The precision recall AUCs calculated by two different packages are different?

Tags: r, classification, auc, precision-recall

I used the dataset cars as an example

```
library("MLmetrics")
library("PRROC")
data(cars)
logreg <- glm(formula = vs ~ hp + wt,
              family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mtcars)
```

The prauc returned by PRAUC is 0.861

```
PRAUC(y_pred = logreg$fitted.values, y_true = mtcars$vs)
```

However, the prauc returned by pr.curve is 0.932

```
pr.curve(scores.class0 = logreg$fitted.values, weights.class0 = mtcars$vs)
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct one is `pr.curve`. If you return the curve from it (via `curve=T` option) and plot at the values (see below), the area *over* the region contains approximately $53$ squares of area $(1/28)^2$, which has area approximately $0.067$, which means under it the area is nearly $0.93$.

[image: pr curve from values]

Sometimes, when the dataset is small, area calculation method matters, which is probably poorly implemented in `MLmetrics`.